# Chance of breaking existing code by adding optional parameter to VB.NET function?

Tags: com, overloading, clr, signature, optional-parameters

Is there a chance that existing code in a large project might bomb if I add a new optional parameter to a function that's used everywhere? I know I can overload the function instead and minimize the risk, but really.. what's the risk if I insist on going with an optional parameter?

Here's an example:

```
    Public Function GetContent(ByVal URL As String, ByVal ID As String, Optional ByRef PageTitle As String = "") As String
        Try
            Dim web As New HtmlWeb()
            Dim doc As HtmlDocument = web.Load(URL)
            ID = "//div[@id='" & ID & "']"
            Dim ContentNode As HtmlNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(ID)

            ' The two lines below are the mere extent of what's new inside this function, besides the new Optional ByRef parameter in its signature
            Dim PageTitleNode As HtmlNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//title")
            If Not PageTitleNode Is Nothing Then PageTitle = PageTitleNode.InnerHtml

            Return ContentNode.InnerHtml

        Catch ex As Exception
            Return "<h4> Bad. Very bad. </h4>"
        End Try
    End Function
```

**PS:** I'd like to comment on my question after the fact, having read others' responses below and having done some additional research myself. Originally, I didn't want to question the validity of the approach of using an optional parameter. That was something VB.NET was allowing me to do and I felt I had every right to use--besides that it was simply very convenient! But my original question had more to do with whether there may be gaps in how optional parameters are implemented, from compilation down to execution--gaps that I should consider as I design my code. I was unaware of the historical significance of the optional parameter approach in relation to the overload approach. I've learned now that it's not that there are gaps or flaws in the optional parameter approach; rather, it was a solution designed for a different and older set of concerns that was simply overridden with the advent of the Common Language Runtime. I'm using VS2013. Sure, everything compiled fine with the optional parameter approach and seemed to run fine but I wanted to confirm I wasn't potentially breaking something else by adding an optional parameter--especially since someone looked at my code and suggested I should overload the function instead. I wanted to prove why I shouldn't keep my optional parameter method. James Thorpe answered that question for me now, I think. But as Tim Schmelter asked, is there a benefit for doing it this way (optional parameters) as opposed to the overload approach? To me now the overload approach seems the best and only way, and that is because I'm using a newer set of technologies that the optional parameter approach--which was implemented for Microsoft's older Component Object Model, or COM--simply wasn't designed to address (see page 83 of the book, ["Microsoft Visual C# 2013 Step By Step" by John Sharp](https://books.google.com/books?id=tkEFCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA83&lpg=PA83&dq=when%20did%20overloading%20start%20being%20supported%20by%20Microsoft%20technologies&source=bl&ots=AVvKD0yor3&sig=xFkRe_8lUVcuHpkhePPLd_XJ7bI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjIieiX7qzXAhXCdSYKHYeSBrMQ6AEIXDAJ#v=onepage&q=when%20did%20overloading%20start%20being%20supported%20by%20Microsoft%20technologies&f=false)). Particularly now, if there are external modules expecting to find the old function signature (i.e., the function parameter layout that existed before I added the new optional parameter), they'll break unless I recompile them too! That's a hindrance for me. But overloading handles this software development problem much better without need for recompilation, something only now supported by the newer Common Languange Runtime, or CLR. I suppose the optional parameter support in VB.NET is more of a historical holdover now from the old COM days--and not the very best solution for my specific requirements. I've also just learned that, "The Common Language Specification, which defines the subset of the CLR that all languages should support, explicitly disallows a reliance on optional parameters. This means they are not a candidate for use in the Base Class Library and will probably never been seen in any of the other libraries shipped as part of the .NET Framework." (from the online article, ["Optional Parameters Are Gaining Ground in .NET", by Jonathan Allen](https://www.infoq.com/news/2010/07/Optional-Parameters)). Although the rules are laxer for us regular developers that consume Microsoft technologies, I think there's something to be said for their internal decision not to rely on optional parameters. I just wanted to post and share that with you in case like me you've also come here wondering!

Comment: If the new optional parameter only adds functionality, it shouldn't, if you change existing functionality without regard to the parameter, then you might have a problem

Comment: If it "bombs" then that's a good thing, not a risk, you'll know you didn't get away with it.  You can't get a warranty, just be sure you recompile everything.

Comment: Right. And I'm not changing the functionality of the code but adding a new optional feature that doesn't change anything that used to be done before inside the function. My only concern is whether there is a chance that other code calling that function from elsewhere might have a hiccup, realizing that there are various sources that depend on how that code was being called.

Comment: _"what's the risk if I insist on going with an optional parameter"_ The question is: _"what's the benefit of using an optional parameter instead of an overload"_?

Comment: I don't want to question the validity of the approach of using an overload. That's something VB.NET is allowing me to do. My question has more to do with whether there may be gaps in how that is currently implemented, from compilation down to execution. I'm using VS2013. Currently everything compiles fine and seems to run fine but I want to be sure.

Comment: @ShieldOfSalvation: of course it's possible that it bombs everywhere now. I'm sure you have added another (optional) parameter not because you don't use it. So you have new code in the method. This code might break your existing code if it contains bugs. But ofc that's not a general answer and it depends on your code. The general answer is: no, a new optional parameter won't break your existing code if the method  body is unchanged.

Comment: I added example code to remove doubts about its plausibility.

Comment: Is this project referenced by any others that call this method?  If you add the optional parameter, will you rebuild those, or would it be expected to be a drop in dll replacement?

Comment: Let's say there were other projects calling it (there is a possibility). Would it break those if I didn't rebuild them? That's the kind of thing I need to know!

Comment: What your code seems to be doing is really adding a new kind of functionality, nl reading the pagetitle of the document you have loaded, I wouldn't keep it in the same code (and can a ByRef really be optional? Is it ever nothing, cause you seem to assign iti with an empty string (my vb.net has been a while)

Comment: Giving the optional argument a default value is required.

Comment: @ShieldOfSalvation I am talking about the `ByRef`. I do believe that what you have created there is bad by design, why not refactor into 3 different functions, one that returns your `doc.documentNode` and to read something by ID and one that can read the title from a documentNode thingie

Comment: Yes I know. This isn't the most desirable way to code this. But I'm not so interested in elegance or best practices right now....I'm more concerned with the viability for introducing new optional parameters to an existing function that's already used elsewhere (possibly in projects I wasn't expecting to recompile).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within a single project?  No, it should be fine.  However, in the comments you said:

> Let's say there were other projects calling it (there is a possibility). Would it break those if I didn't rebuild them?

Optional parameters are actually baked in at compile time, so if you have your original method signature:

```
Public Function GetContent(ByVal URL As String, ByVal ID As String)
```

And someone is calling it thusly:

```
GetContent(someUrl, someId)
```

It will be compiled into their assembly as-is.  With your new optional parameter, anything calling it as above without passing in the parameter would actually get compiled as:

```
GetContent(someUrl, someId, "")
```

Note how the default value of the optional parameter has automatically been brought in.  If you're rebuilding everything, it's all good.  However, in those projects that are referencing this one that *aren't rebuilt*, they will have the original two-parameter call.  Your `GetContent` method now requires 3 parameters at runtime - you'll get a runtime error as it can't find an overload of the function that still takes 2 parameters.

Comment: That sucks. So nothing in CLR or somehow within the .NET framework will spot this issue and dynamically resolve it without throwing an error?

Comment: @ShieldOfSalvation I'm not aware of anything, no

Comment: If this is so, then introducing optional parameters to existing code has a VERY big caveat. It's got to be recorded somewhere in Microsoft documentation, I'd hope. Haven't yet found it. I've only found that "Optional parameters could already be defined in Visual Basic since .NET 1.0", per Microsoft (https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/614070/c-optional-parameter-ambiguous-call-compile-time-warning-needed).

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can do it without breaking code...

```
Public Function GetContent(ByVal URL As String, ByVal ID As String, ByRef PageTitle As String = "") As String
    ' the rest of your function here
End Function

Public Function GetContent(ByVal URL As String, ByVal ID As String) As String
    Return GetContent(URL, ID, "")
End Function
```

That way you have a version of the function with 2 parameters for the existing code and one with 3.

If you want to encourage programmers to switch to the 3 parameter version, then you can mark the 2 parameter version like this:

```
<Obsolete("Use the version that takes pageTitle as a 3rd parameter">
Public Function GetContent(ByVal URL As String, ByVal ID As String) As String
    Return GetContent(URL, ID, "")
End Function
```

That will give you a compiler warning if you try to call the 2-parameter version.

Comment: This is an excellent solution to my coding problem, but as I said in my original question I understand there is a function overloading alternative but with my StackOverflow post I'd like rather to clear up whether the optional parameter route is inherently flawed or inadequate--which so far it seems it is.